# Packages for Tree implementation in C# that are similar to Anytree in python?

Tags: c#, tree, anytree

My application needs to find all the leaf nodes and then find traversals from the root to the leaves. Is there a good package for Tree implementation in C# that can do this? I need something similar to Anytree in python.

Comment: Trees can be a little complex, but I like this library: https://github.com/sestoft/C5